# javaScript runtime error: 'kendo' is undefined

Tags: javascript, kendo-grid

I have an application that uses kendo grid, and when I try to run the application, I get this error

> JavaScript runtime error: 'kendo' is undefined

Below is my code. Where do I need to define kendo?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />  

<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>  


<div id="rpViewContent" class="view-content">
    <div id="purchdGrid"
            data-role="grid"
            data-resizable="true"
            data-navigatable="true"
            data-editable="true"
            data-pageable="false"
            data-columns="[
                { 'field': 'PO', 'title': '<b>PO #', 'width': 65 },
                { 'field': 'Line', 'title': '<b>Line #', 'width': 65 },
                { 'field': 'Item', 'title': '<b>Item #', 'width': 65 },
            ]"
            data-bind="source:purchDataSource"
            style="height: 55%">
    </div></div>  
    <script>
        var viewModel = kendo.observable({
            purchDataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
                schema: {
                    model: {
                        id: "ID",
                        fields: {
                            Line: { type: "string" },
                            Item: { type: "string" }
                        }
                    }
                },
                data: [
                    { ID: "43824", Line: "1", Item: "Thus is a test 1" },
                    { ID: "43825", Line: "2", Item: "Thus is a test 2" },
                    { ID: "43826", Line: "3", Item: "Thus is a test 3" }
                ]
            })
        });
        kendo.bind($("#purchViewContent"), viewModel);
    </script>
```

Comment: Where does the kendo object come from?

Comment: where is the js file?

Comment: Do you need to initilise kendo? For instance: var kendo = new Kendo();

Comment: Have you checked that the request for `kendo.all.min.js` is successful?

Comment: @Richard yes, I have....

Comment: @NeilMunro, your suggestion did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @user990423 It really was more of a question than a suggestion... <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />  

    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>  
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      console.log(kendo);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>

Works for me...

Comment: @NeilMunro can you post that in the answer section? I copied your code, but it's not working for me.

Comment: This answer solved my error

Answer (score 1):

This snippet shows a valid Kendo object, ensure your link and script tags are in the correct place in the HTML document.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.common.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/styles/kendo.default.min.css" />  
  </head>
  <body>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://cdn.kendostatic.com/2015.2.624/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>  
    <script>
      console.log(kendo);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```